# Resizing an image bounding box after scaling in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator, images

Good morning,

I have imported a drawing from Adobe Illustrator Draw to illustrator CC.
  I then had to scale it down to about 60%.

My bounding box is staying at the original size. 
Resetting the bounding box under `object > transform > reset bounding box` is not working.

Any ideas please!

Comment: I don't understand your question. You imported a drawing from Illustrator to Illustrator? Between different versions? Is it all vector or is there a bitmap in your image?

Comment: @Luciano [Illustrator Draw](http://www.adobe.com/products/draw.html) is a separate program that is a mobile application.

Comment: Yes, Luciano, Illustrator Draw is a mobile app.  I subscribe to Creative Cloud and that allows you to send your drawings from  Illustrator Draw to Adobe Illustrator on your laptop/desktop.  It imports as a vector. It is amazing! ( I am a student and have only use Creative Cloud.)  As long as AI is open on your computer you can send from your mobile device from anywhere, as long as AI is open.  (If I am out, and AI is open on my laptop at home;  I can send the drawing from wherever I am and when I get home . . . there is it!) Thank you for your response.

Comment: I imported it again and it is sized correctly.  Thank you for your comment and help.

Comment: Rachelle, if you found a solution to your question, please consider posting it as an answer and marking it as the correct answer. This is good for site stats and for any future visitors who might have the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The "Reset Bounding Box" function resets the bounding box when you have rotated the object which doesn't sound like the issue you're having.

[image: rotate box]

I would check to see if there is an invisible object that is grouped with your graphic or if there is a clipping mask.

Comment: Thank you, Andrew.  There is not a clipping mask nor an invisible object. I think it must be because the vector was imported from my mobile app and then resized . . .

Comment: @RachelleSher I just downloaded the app to see, I am unable to produce your problem. If you add a screenshot of what you see in Illustrator (a before and after resizing with the bounding box and maybe the layers panel expanded) that might help us be able to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: I imported it again, Andrew and it sized properly this time.  I think the first time I did it as an image and this time I did it correctly as a vector. Thank you for getting back to me.